# File Upload to WCF REST

Tags: javascript, wcf

We are uploading file from JavaScript to WCF REST. Used byte array in both places (JS and WCF). We are getting below error while hitting WCF service.

**"The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter FileContents. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type DocumentObject. End element 'FileContents' from namespace"**

Comment: File is a stream, that need to upload. It is converting into bye[] array. so where is html here.

Comment: post your code that you are using